# How to display separate titles on each page in Django

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I have a Django website where I have separated the html files into a `base.html` file as so:

```
{% include 'head.html' %}

<body>
    {% include 'nav.html' %}

    {% block content %}
    {% endblock content %}

    {% include 'footer.html' %}

    {% include 'scripts.html' %}
</body>


</html>
```

Due to including `head.html`, the title on each page is the same, since `head.html` has only 1 title. Here is the `head.html` file:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/materialize.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/materialize.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/custom.css' %}">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>mytitle</title>
</head>
```

But i want to display different titles for different pages and I dont know how to. Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

base.html

```
{% include 'head.html' with  title=title %}

<body>
    {% include 'nav.html' %}

    {% block content %}
    {% endblock content %}

    {% include 'footer.html' %}

    {% include 'scripts.html' %}
</body>


</html>
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
    context = {
       "title":"Home"
     }
   return render(request,"template",context)
```

head.html

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/materialize.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/materialize.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/custom.css' %}">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>{{title}}</title>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

use **include** instead of extend for base.html and pass dynamic title to base.html

django link : [include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#include)

```
{% include "base.html" with objects=website.title %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **blocks** which are [overridable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance):

head.html

```
...
<title>{% block page_title %}{% endblock %}</title>
```

my_concrete_page.html

```
{% extends base.html %}

{% block page_title %}my concrete title{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am giving this answer from my knowledge:

Make one file for this :
head.html

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/materialize.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/materialize.min.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/custom.css' %}">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

make different file for your different title : 
title1.html

```
<title>mytitle</title>
```

title2.html

```
<title>mytitle</title>
```

now add in your main file like this :

```
<head>
{% include 'head.html' %}
{% include 'title1.html' %}
</head>
<body>
    {% include 'nav.html' %}

    {% block content %}
    {% endblock content %}

    {% include 'footer.html' %}

    {% include 'scripts.html' %}
</body>


</html>
```

I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I had to combine the ideas of @Ivan and @Soham. I removed the title tag from my `head.html` and added that to my `base.html`. Along with that I used overrideable block tag inside the title tag. So now my `base.html` looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

{% include 'head.html' %}
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock title %}</title>

<body>
    {% include 'nav.html' %}

    {% block content %}
    {% endblock content %}

    {% include 'footer.html' %}

    {% include 'scripts.html' %}
</body>


</html>
```

And all I have to do now is use the tags accordingly in other pages:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}whatever i want the title to be{% endblock title %}
```

Comment: this is invalid html tho because the <title> must be in the <head>

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1. Base.html file**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}"
.
.
<title>{% block title %} Home-title {% endblock %}</title>
```

**Then add like this code your file**

```
{% block title %} Search Results {% endblock %}
```

**Option 2. To query a model in the view:**

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block title %} {{blog_obj.title}} {% endblock %}
{% block content %}
```